# How to call azure function created using visual studio in logic app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Deployed the azure function app using visual studio in azure, where it is having some azure functions how to call one of the azure function from function app using logic app

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the function in the logic app like this:

[image]

For more details, please see this offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps

Comment: I am having a multiple azure functions within the azure function app where they are triggered using service bus quee.How to call those functions using service bus quee.If the functions are triggered using http request then they will called using the above featuer